# Searching an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a program having 3 parallel arrays one that holds 4 digit student ID the second the student Name and the last one that holds the GPA and the size of the arrays have to be 10
also the program be able to do a Student ID search and if it doesnt exist to show an error message

the first part works fine but when it comes to the searching it doesnt work

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentIDArray
 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int option;
    String inputString;
    inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome"
            +" Choose the option you will like"
            + " \n1. Enter Student  Information "
            + "\n2. Search for Student");
    option = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    if(option ==1)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the Student");
        String[] studentname = new String[10];

        for(int i =0; i<studentname.length; i++)
        {

            studentname[i] = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the 4 digit Student ID");
        int[] studentID = new int[10];
        for(int x=0; x<studentID.length; x++)
        {
            studentID[x] = in.nextInt();
        }



        System.out.println("Enter the Student's Grade Point Average");
        int[] gpa = new int[10];
        for(int y=0; y<studentID.length; y++)
        {
            gpa[y] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        searching();
    }




}

public static void searching()
{

    int idnumber,
        results;
    int[]studentID = null;

    String inputString;
    inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the ID number");
    idnumber = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    results = sequentialSearch(studentID, idnumber);
    if (results == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("no information");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("yeii congrats");
    }

}


public static int sequentialSearch(int[] studentID, int value)
{
      int index;
      int element;
      boolean found;

      index =0;

      element = -1;
      found = false;

      while(!found && index < studentID.length)
      {
        if (studentID[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            element = index;
        }
        index++;
      }
      return element;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it easier to understand now?

Comment: Can you clarify some points?

When you want user to type student name or ID, does user have to type it character by character? You've mentioned they have to be stored in arrays and arrays have to take max 10 elements. But you want 4-digit ID from user, but you still want 10 user input. I think you got the "10 element array" thing wrong. Can it be "the input size must not exceed 10 characters"?
You want to search your previously saved student data but you have not saved those data into an object and when you want to search, you don't search from any place.
Consider changing these fatal errors.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that you are declaring the `studentID` array locally to your methods.

Make it a class member instead (an instance member would be preferred, but all your methods are static), so that your methods are working on the same array, not on different ones:

```
public class StudentIDArray
{
    private static int[] studentID = new int[10];
    ...
```

Note that this limits the number of entries to the size of the array and you will get exceptions if you exceed these limits. Consider using a `Vector` or an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
searching(studentID);
```

Pass the studentID array to the searching method instead of declaring it again.

```
public static void searching(int[] studentID)
{

    int idnumber,
        results;
    //int[]studentID = null;

    String inputString;
    inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the ID number");
    idnumber = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    results = sequentialSearch(studentID, idnumber);
    if (results == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("no information");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("yeii congrats");
    }

}


public static int sequentialSearch(int[] studentID, int value)
{
      int index;
      int element;
      boolean found;

      index =0;

      element = -1;
      found = false;

      while(!found && index < studentID.length)
      {
        if (studentID[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            element = index;
        }
        index++;
      }
      return element;
    }
```

A better approach would be to keep it as a static/class variable as @Andreas pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

These are the Running Steps of Program....
     First Step => Enter Size of Array.
     Second Step =>  Enter Member of Array.
     Third Step  => Enter Searching Integer of Array.

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Searching 
        {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                 int temp =-1;
                Scanner user_input=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter Size Of Array ");

                int Size=user_input.nextInt();
                int[] a=new int[Size];
                //Scan input Array.
                System.out.println("Enter element Of an Array...");
                for(int j=0;j<Size;j++)
                {
                    a[j]=user_input.nextInt();
                }

               System.out.println("The contents of the Array are :");
               //Print input Arrray
               for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
               {
                  System.out.println("array[" + i + "] = " + a[i]);
               }

                System.out.println("Enter Integer For Searching..");
                int Search=user_input.nextInt();
               //Searching in an Array.
                for(int index=0;index<a.length; index++)
                {
                    if(a[index]==Search)
                    {
                        temp=index;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(temp!=-1)
                {
                    System.out.println(" The search element is : " + Search);
                    System.out.println(" It is found in the array at position : " + temp);      
                }
                else
                  System.out.println("\n Element not Found..");
            }
         }
```